# Wifi adapter did not work in hp pavilion 15-au172tx laptop

Tags: 16.04

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 for hp pavilion 15-au172tx laptop but wifi did not work. This laptop is 7th gen and is there any problem with it? I also tried to get wifi adapter type but i can't and i also tried additional driver application to add drivers but wifi adapter is not see in that application. Please help me

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; uname -a`

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 3168 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.0 Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
Linux HP-Pavilion-Notebook 4.4.0-93-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 21:17:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; uname -a` terminal command.

Comment: i have upload that

Comment: Post output as text, not as a screenshot. You need to upgrade kernel. If you installed 16.04.3, it would immediately work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to internet by wire and run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-firmware
```

and reboot.

This device is supported by newer kernels.